# BaseX get line-breaks return between node-data

Tags: xml, formatting, xquery, basex

I'm using BaseX as my XML based DB. I make a simple query like

```
xquery for $Book in 
/Libraray/Literaturelist/Literature/Title return fn:data($Book)
```

I get all titles, just as a String that has got no line breaks.

Is there a way to add line-breaks with XQuery after each node found by the query to separate the data? This is not really dependant on my XML file because I do not add line-breaks hardcoded within the tags. ;)

Answer (score 2):

it depends on how you retrieve the query results. The most elegant way is to use the iterator, as e.g. shown in:

```
http://basex.org/code/QueryExample
```

Apart from that, you could extend your XQuery by returning an additional newline:

```
xquery for $Book in /Libbraray/Literaturelist/Literature/Title
return (fn:data($Book), '
')
```

Note, however, that the additionally output space character cannot be suppressed.

Best,
Christian

PS: feel free to use the basex-talk mailing list to get feedback more quickly.

Comment: Why does the additional space character occur?

Comment: Sicco: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-30/ -> sequence normalization. Yet you may overcome this by joining the sequence manually (this works only for strings, and essentially means returning a new sequence of length 1):  `string-join(for $i in 1 to 10 return xs:string($i), "&#10;")`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to add a newline is to explicitly use the character reference for a newline:

```
xquery for $Book in /Libbraray/Literaturelist/Literature/Title
return (fn:data($Book), "&#10;")
```

Answer (score 0):

The [XQuery 3.1 Serialization](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/#adaptive-output) specification provides the new "adaptive" serialization mode, which outputs each XQuery result on a new line. Since BaseX 8, this mode is used as new default.