# xQuery XML tokenize a string

Tags: xml, xquery, tokenize

I'm new to xQuery and can't seem to get the following to work:

```
<measInfo measInfoId="1542455297">
  <measTypes>1542455297 1542455298 1542455299 1542455300 1542455301 1542455302 1542455303 1542455304 1542455305 1542455306 1542455307 1542460296 1542460297 </measTypes>
  <measValue measObjLdn="LTHAB0113422/ETHPORT:Cabinet No.=0, Subrack No.=1, Slot No.=7, Port No.=0, Subboard Type=BASE_BOARD">
    <measResults>116967973 585560 496041572 682500 0 12583680 72080 520454 46670568 73432 2205837 1000000 1000000 </measResults>
  </measValue>
  <measValue measObjLdn="LTHAB0113422/ETHPORT:Cabinet No.=0, Subrack No.=1, Slot No.=7, Port No.=1, Subboard Type=BASE_BOARD">
    <measResults>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 </measResults>
  </measValue>
</measInfo>
```

I'm using //measInfo/measTypes/fn:tokenize(text(),'\s+'). I was hoping would return a record for each space delimited value, however it return the same as   //measInfo/measTypes/text()

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Eh? It's returning a record for each space-delimited value when I run it (in BaseX).

Comment: I'm using http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery to test the code, what site are you using?

Comment: Not a site, a (downloadable, installable) XQuery database (with a very nice GUI): http://basex.org/. BaseX stays quite close to the leading edge of the XQuery standard during its development process, so it's well-suited as a test platform for current versions of the language.

Comment: That said, I get the same result reported in my answer from the web site you link. Perhaps you're (mis)interpreting its output as a single string from the way it's rendering a sequence? That's why I modified my form of the query to put `<item>`s around results, to make it clear that `fn:tokenize` **really is** distinguishing them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BaseX get line-breaks return between node-data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073035/basex-get-line-breaks-return-between-node-data)

Comment: ...amended my answer to also show injecting literal newlines between results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XQuery 3.0 (as implemented by BaseX), this actually *does* work:

```
declare context item := document {
<measInfo measInfoId="1542455297">
<measTypes>1542455297 1542455298 1542455299 1542455300 1542455301 1542455302 1542455303 1542455304 1542455305 1542455306 1542455307 1542460296 1542460297 </measTypes>
<measValue measObjLdn="LTHAB0113422/ETHPORT:Cabinet No.=0, Subrack No.=1, Slot No.=7, Port No.=0, Subboard Type=BASE_BOARD">
    <measResults>116967973 585560 496041572 682500 0 12583680 72080 520454 46670568 73432 2205837 1000000 1000000 </measResults>
</measValue>
<measValue measObjLdn="LTHAB0113422/ETHPORT:Cabinet No.=0, Subrack No.=1, Slot No.=7, Port No.=1, Subboard Type=BASE_BOARD">
    <measResults>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 </measResults>
</measValue>
</measInfo>
};

for $item in //measInfo/measTypes/fn:tokenize(text(),'\s+')
return <item>{$item}</item>
```

...returns...

```
<item>1542455297</item>
<item>1542455298</item>
<item>1542455299</item>
<item>1542455300</item>
<item>1542455301</item>
<item>1542455302</item>
<item>1542455303</item>
<item>1542455304</item>
<item>1542455305</item>
<item>1542455306</item>
<item>1542455307</item>
<item>1542460296</item>
<item>1542460297</item>
<item/>
```

---

Putting `<item>` around each result ensures that the rendering of these results makes each item visually distinct -- otherwise, you could have each result rendered into a single line of text, and it wouldn't be obvious to the reader whether they were split into multiple items by `fn:tokenize()` or not.

---

Another way to do this is to inject literal newlines:

```
for $item in //measInfo/measTypes/fn:tokenize(text(),'\s+')
return ($item, "&#10;")
```